# Add button not showing up in Django tutorial 02

Tags: python, django, admin, addition

I am new to Django and have been going through the official tutorial on www.djangoproject.com. I have successfully implemented the tutorial 1 in my system but I am unable to figure out why the **"plus" or "add" button is not showing up** in the admin panel.

I am using **django 1.6.1** 
It is a pretty simple code but I am unable to figure it out since I don't have any prior knowledge of Django. Help will be appreciated.

Below is the code for the files models.py and admin.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
         return self.choice_text
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

"""class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date')
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['question']
"""
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is unclear why are the classes in the `admin.py` written inside the string in triple quotes.

Assuming this is a typo/intentional, you still need to `register()` the `PollAdmin`:

```
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

---

The complete code at this step should look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]

admin.site.register(Choice)
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Comment: I was just trying to model the code as it was in the tutorial, that's why the the triple quotes. But it did solve the problem, register() the PollAdmin class. 
Thanks a lot man :)