# Add button not showing in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add the related objects from django tutorial of it's documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07

But there is no add button showing in it

I've checked this answer too but it did not help [Add button not showing up in Django tutorial 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701147/add-button-not-showing-up-in-django-tutorial-02)

This is my admin.py

```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals

   from django.contrib import admin
   from home.models import *

   # Register your models here.

   class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
       model = Choice
       extra = 3
   class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       fieldsets = [
                    (None,{'fields': ['question_text']}),
                    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
                   ]
       inlines = [ChoiceInline]

   admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

This is my models.py

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import models


    # Create your models here.
    class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


    class Choice(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

[This is showing in my admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB1dg.png)

python used is python 2.7

Comment: Where do you think you should be seeing an add button?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I suspect this is about the 'add another choice' button that you'd expect on the inline.

Comment: Have you modified any admin templates or do you have any errors in the console when viewing the page?

Comment: The missing "add another" buttons use JavaScript, so I think that could be where the problem is. Make sure that JavaScript is enabled for your browser, and check the console in your development tools for errors. If you have changed Django versions, then run collectstatic to make sure you have the latest version of the staticfiles (no need to do this if you're using runserver) and refresh the page so that your browser reloads the javascript.

Comment: @markwalker_ I haven't changed the admin template at all, and there are no errors shown in the console.

Comment: @Alasdair I am using the same django version at all times. ANd yes I am using 'runserver' only and tried reloading, but still no result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to register the model Choice as well.

```
# admin.py
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Comment: I tried that too, still the same result. I believe that we register any model on the admin.py only to show that particular model and its contents in the admin page of the website.

Answer (score 1):

From your code I see you are using a StackedInline View.

When using these type of views it's very likely for the Add button to disappear, especially if you are messing with `extra` and `max_num` properties.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra):

> The dynamic link will not appear if the number of currently displayed forms exceeds max_num, or if the user does not have JavaScript enabled.

So you might need to adjust the `extra` and `max_num` properties in order to make the Add button show up again.